# How to properly load build folder in WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, wordpress

I am trying to convert my html to WordPress.

I have two folders, one is `build` folder which consist of:

```
-index.css
-index.js
-index-style.css
```

Then on my other folder which called `src`:

```
-index.js
-modules folder
--HeroSlider.js
--GoogleMap.js
```

I tried to load the HeroSlider.js on my function.js file on my WordPress theme folder like this:

```
<?php 

function school_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('main-school-js', get_theme_file_uri('/src/index.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-font', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i"');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"');
    wp_enqueue_style('school_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'school_files');
```

But this one did not load my Hero Slider file on my WordPress file. How do I load it so i can make sure the template works?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code maybe useful for you.

```
/**
 * enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function school_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('main-school-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/src/index.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-font', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i"');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"');
    wp_enqueue_style('school_main_styles', get_template_directory_uri(). '/build/index.css', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'school_files');
```